# Generic glue-up shower wall panels?

Tags: shower

I installed a 32x32-feet inch shower pan. The shower has walls on three sides. I was planning to install glue-up plastic panels for the shower walls, but all the ones I can find at the big box stores are either shockingly expensive or won't fit.

So, I'm wondering if there's a generic type of material I could cut to size and install using construction adhesive. For instance, could I just buy 4x8-foot PVC sheets?

I know I could also do wall tile on cement board, but this is a rental property and I don't want to spend a lot of time and money.

Comment: Fiberglass reinforced plastic FRP  is commonly used for such applications   Google FRP panel installation

Comment: There are many styles to choose from in FRP panels http://www.marlite.com/designer-wall-systems-frp-wall-panels.aspx. Big box stores usually only stock one style but it can be ordered in more attractive options

Answer (score 1):

After having a number of shower walls deteriorate in just a few years, I paneled a stall shower with an underlayment of [cement board](https://www.homedepot.com/p/DUROCK-EdgeGuard-1-4-in-x-3-ft-x-5-ft-Cement-Board-170215/304218901) and covered it with [fiberglass reinforced plastic (FRP) wall board](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Panolam-4-ft-x-8-ft-White-090-FRP-Wall-Board-H090WTT48096CF/305900400) and [corner molding](https://www.homedepot.com/p/854-1-2-in-x-7-8-in-x-8-ft-PVC-FRP-Inside-Corner-Moulding-White-0085408011/100576770?MERCH=REC-_-PIPHorizontal1_rr-_-305900400-_-100576770-_-N) (links are for reference purpose only).

The project cost less than US$100 and has held up for ~15 years. In fact, the shower base needs cosmetic touch-up, but the walls are fine, and water infiltration has been eliminated.

Comment: Thanks -- this is the answer I was hoping for. Follow up question: Is cement board underlayment specifically required, or did you choose to add it for additional water protection? (I guess I can do it either way -- it's cheap and will be fast to put up -- but I'm curious if the FRP manufacturers require it.)

Comment: Cement board is usually a good idea in any potentially damp spot, and for the amount used around a stall shower, adds little expense. Previously, there was ordinary gypsum-based wallboard, which crumbled due to the humidity and leaks. FRP is actually waterproof, except at the joints, so it *might* be used over sheetrock.